# Expression Engine - Hide Item if No Entry in Category

Tags: if-statement, expressionengine

I am building a site in Expression Engine with a hard-coded navigation. I need to hide one of the nav items until the client makes an entry under a certain category, here's what I have right now:

```
{exp:channel:entries category_name="name" limit="1"}
  {if count > 0}
    <li> &bull; <a href="#">Link</a></li>
  {if:else}
    (don't show anything)
  {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Got it, I was way overcomplicating things.
Just added my channel names and removed the "if." Win.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, exactly. If there is nothing there, it just won't show anything. If you needed to add a placeholder or something, you could use the {if no_results} tag.